# Pass data from parent to child via selectors on click event

Tags: angular6

I have a parent-child component relationship. I want to pass data from the parent to child continuously on click of a button.

parent.componet.ts

```
 data = '';
change(){
 data = 'new data';
 }
```

parent.component.html

```
  <child [parent_data]='data'></child>
  <button (click)="change()">Change</button>
```

child.component.ts

```
  @Input() parent_data = '';
```

child.componet.ts

```
   {{parent_data}}
```

Once the child component is loaded via selector, the change don't seem to have an effect or the child component is not aware of it. I was under the impression after a change of data, child component auto knows the changes.

How do I pass new data to the child from the parent once it is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your problem as below plnkr. But it is working fine as expected.

https://plnkr.co/edit/WoZZnb9CKSEaqP08HrxI?p=preview

```
<child [parent_data]='data'></child>
<button (click)="change()">Change</button>
```

For more information about two way data binding please check

https://medium.com/@preethi.s/angular-custom-two-way-data-binding-3e618309d6c7